# Animate image independent of mask?

Tags: css, image

I'm trying to find a way to animate an image which has a masked applied to it without affecting the mask itself.

This has been the best cross-browser way I've found to apply a mask, but I'm uncertain how to apply CSS animations to it in such a way I can have the center image rotate inside the mask, and not both at the same time.

For example, my current code just rotates the entire image and mask together.
*HTML*

```
<div class="svgMask">
    <svg width="726" height="726" baseProfile="full" version="1.2">
        <defs>
            <mask id="svgmask2" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" transform="scale(1)">
                <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://www.mikerezl.com/img/testmask.png"/>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <image id="interior" mask="url(#svgmask2)" width="100%" height="100%" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="http://www.mikerezl.com/img/valknut.jpg"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#interior {
 -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
 -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
 -moz-animation-name: rotate;
 -moz-animation-duration:2s;
 -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {  -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

[***Fiddle link***](http://jsfiddle.net/auavm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the origin like this (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/f5RE4/1/)

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

but for me performance is horrible and firefox isnt working. i would suggest using a canvas to composite your image and animating on that.

```
context.save();
context.drawImage(valknut, 0, 0);
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
context.drawImage(mask, 0, 0);
context.restore();
```

by using a canvas you gain a lot of control! heres an example of how you would achieve this with a canvas (http://jsfiddle.net/f5RE4/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself clearly. I'm attempting to make the image underneath the mask rotate while the actual mask is stationary. This would give the effect of the overall shape being static while the actual interior rotates independently. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, you can achieve this in canvas still (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/f5RE4/5/). It would be better to be able to do it in CSS but i don't think its possible to do it crossbrowser with CSS. But here is a working version in webkit in pure CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/k9t5e/246/).